# prove $\lim_{x \rightarrow 3} x^2 =9 $

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, epsilon-delta

"The first thing we 'll do is to require that $|x-3|<1$" from Spivak. But why he fix the $\delta$ ? The defintion only allow us to fix the $\epsilon$. Suppose the case  $\lim_{x\rightarrow1} 1/x $, fix $\delta=1$ won't work. Instead I try

$|x^2-9|=|x^2-6x+9+6x-18|<|x-3|^2 + 6|x-3|=|x-3|(|x-3|+6)< \epsilon < \epsilon^2/36 +\epsilon$
Since I choose $\delta =\epsilon/6$

Comment: He did not fix the $\delta$. He ounly bounds the $\delta$ above by $1$, i.e. makes sure that $\delta\leq 1$ is always true. If you read the proof to its end, you will notice it is not said anywhere that $\delta=1$.

Comment: Per the definition, given any $\epsilon$, a definition such as $$\delta = \min\left[ ~\frac{\epsilon}{k}, r ~\right],$$ where positive numbers $k$ and $r$ are decided by you, to ease your analysis, is perfectly acceptable.  That is, if you can show that there exist fixed positive constants $k,r$ that yield the desired implication, **for any value** $~\epsilon,~$ then the result is perfectly valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll explain as I usually do by setting $u=x-3\to 0$

It may appear overworking it with such a simple limit, but keep in mind that our mathematical toolbox is richer regarding limits in $0$ or $\infty$.

Rewriting $|x^2-9|=|(x-3)(x+3)|=|u(u+6)|=\underbrace{|u|}_{\to 0}\times\underbrace{|u+6|}_{\text{bounded}}$

- $|x-3|<\delta$ translates immediately to $|u|<\delta$
- $u\to 0$ so it eventually is less than $1$ leading to $|u+6|<|u|+6<7$ which is bounded.

So we have two conditions to fulfil:

- $|u|<\delta$ with $\delta=\varepsilon$ to get the delta-epsilon proof going on
- $|u|<\delta$ with $\delta=1$ to be able to bound $|u+6|$

Note we have chosen $\delta=1$ but you realize that any positive number is suitable, could have been $\frac 12$ or could have been $1000$.

Both conditions are realized simultaneously when $\delta=\min(1,\varepsilon)$

And you get $|x^2-9|=|u||u+6|< 7\varepsilon$

You can eventually choose another $\delta=\min(1,\frac{\varepsilon}7)$ but this is pure aesthetic to get a bare epsilon at the end, it is not really requested. As long as you have $cst\times \epsilon$ this is fine.

Remark:

*Why will you say, do we bother taking $\delta=\min(1,\varepsilon)$, since $\varepsilon$ is so small already, the condition is equivalent to $\delta=\varepsilon$ anyway, isn't it ?*

In fact the limit definition does not explicitly says that epsilon is small, it says

$\forall \varepsilon>0,\ \exists \delta>0\ \text{ s.t. }|x-x_0|<\delta\implies |f(x)-\ell|<\varepsilon$

It is "for all" epsilons, possibly one million, possibly one million$^{th}$, though implicitly we are only interested in the small ones.

Therefore this $\delta=\min(1,\varepsilon)$ is just to cope with this definition.

Comment: You mean we could give $\delta$ some number and check for which $\epsilon$ it apply and then we do"choose delta depend on the epsilon" which less than the one we found cause "we are only interested in the small ones"?